# Simple tokenizer in C

Tags: c, lexical-analysis

I implemented a simple tokenizer. Would love to hear your feedback on code style, best practices:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "lexer.h"
#include "mem.h"

static inline int delimiter(char c);

char **lexer_tokenize(const char *s) {
    char **rv, **tmp;
    int i, j, k, len, cap;

    cap = 4;
    rv = mem_malloc(sizeof(char *) * cap);
    for (i = 0, j = 0, len = 0;; j++) {
        if (delimiter(s[j]) && i < j) {
            if (len == cap - 1) {
                cap <<= 1;
                if ((tmp = mem_realloc(rv, sizeof(char *) * cap))) {
                    mem_free(rv);
                    rv = tmp;
                } else {
                    mem_free(rv);
                    rv = 0;
                    fprintf(stderr, "tokenize: error resizing result array.\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            rv[len] = mem_malloc(sizeof(char) * (j - i + 1));
            for (k = 0; (rv[len][k++] = s[i++]) != s[j];)
                ;
            rv[len++][k] = 0;
            if (!s[j])
                break;
            i = j + 1;
        }
    }
    rv[len] = 0;
    return rv;
}

static inline int delimiter(char c) {
    return c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == 0 || c == EOF;
}
```

Would also love to hear tips on performance improvements.

Comment: Could you state what exactly constitutes a token in your language?

Comment: @200_success An english word (excluding punctuation symbols). I'm working on a top-down parser as a learning exercise (trying to learn natural language understanding).

Comment: this is missing the contents of the two 'home grown' header files   without the contents of the header files, the code is incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Apparent uniform formatting - good**

Hope OP is using an auto-formatter.

**Bug?**

`mem_free(rv)` is suspicious.  Is a *free* needed on successful re-allocation?

```
        if ((tmp = mem_realloc(rv, sizeof(char *) * cap))) {
            mem_free(rv);
```

**Insufficient documentation**

"a simple tokenizer" is insufficient to describe `lexer_tokenize()` functionality.  I'd hope to see that in the not-included "lexer.h".

Sample usage would have been informative.

OP comments about [punctuation symbols](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/276172/simple-tokenizer-in-c/276188#comment547000_276172) yet nothing in code suggests anything dealing with punctuation symbols.

**O(n*n) vs. O(n)**

With the nested loops code *looks* O(n*n).  I'd expect a tokenizer to be O(n).  As is, code is unclear to me.

**`EOF` is not a character of a *string***

```
// return c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == 0 || c == EOF;
return c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == 0;
```

**Consider any *whitespace***

`'\t'`, `'\r'`, `'\f'`, `'\v'` are white-spaces too.

```
#include <ctype.h>

static inline int delimiter(char c) {
  // return c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == 0;
  return isspace((unsigned char) c) || c == 0;
}
```

**No checking for allocation failure**

As `mem_malloc()` can return a failure indication, `NULL`, check for that and handle appropriately.

**Declare objects when needed**

```
// char **rv;
// ... 
// rv = mem_malloc(sizeof(char *) * cap);
char **rv = mem_malloc(sizeof(char *) * cap);
```

**Allocate to the refenced object, not the type**

It is easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// rv = mem_malloc(sizeof(char *) * cap);
char **rv = mem_malloc(sizeof rv[0] * cap);

// rv[len] = mem_malloc(sizeof(char) * (j - i + 1));
rv[len] = mem_malloc(sizeof rv[len][0] * (j - i + 1));
```

**Validate "lexer.h" independence**

I assume this code is in "lexer.c" and the `lexer_tokenize()` declaration is in "lexer.h".

Rather than include `#include <stdio.h>`, then `#include "lexer.h"`, reverse that to test `"lexer.h"` has no need for prior includes.

**`int` vs. `size_t`**

`int` is not certainly wide enough.  `size_t` is the type for any sizeof of an object or indexing.  Note that `size_t` is an *unsigned* type.

```
// int i, j, k, len, cap;
size_t i, j, k, len, cap;
```

**Informative names**

`i, j, k` are not informative object names other than they are indexes - but how to they differ?  What are they for?

Comment: I didn't get the "Validate "lexer.h" independence" section? Should I always include the deps in header rather than implementation?

Comment: @kovac A user `"xxx.h"` file should include all the included files that `.h` file needs and no extra.  Useful for the corresponding `"xxx.c"` to test that by including it first.

Comment: I agree that the code should be commented more.